# What affects the damping of a spring?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

What variables affect the damping of a spring executing simple harmonic motion?

What are the independent variables, and what variables would need to be controlled in an experiment?

I'm attempting to complete an investigation where I measure the decrease in amplitude of a damped spring, and to prove the relationship between variables in the motion.

Thanks!

Comment: An interesting paper partially addressing your question: http://prd.aps.org/abstract/PRD/v42/i8/p2437_1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should already be familiar with damping.  It simply refers to the fact that if you set a spring going, it eventually stops.

[The wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping) should cover most of what you want to know.

Any particular spring may be damped for all sorts of reasons.  Any way the spring can lose energy contributes to damping, so it could be lost internally to heat due to stressing the material, or externally to heat via friction, or externally to an electromagnetic field, to some sort of mechanical [dashpot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dashpot), etc.

If you were designing an experiment to study damping, you could be interested in a number of different particular things.  You will have to make your own choice about what the most interesting thing to study is.  For example, would you like measure the [damping ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_ratio)?  The overall magnitude of the damping effect?  The time it takes your spring to reduce its amplitude to 1/2 its previous value?

If you have a particular effect picked out, do you want to know how it depends on the load on the spring, or the material of the spring, or whether the spring is in a vacuum, etc.  There are many possible things to study, so your question has no definite answer.  I'm sure you can find something particular you find worthwhile.

Comment: In regards to an experiment, it will likely be investigating damping considering only frictional forces. I'm intending to measure the gradual decrease in the amplitude of a spring.

It sounds like the dampening ratio will be relevant in that scenario. I've read the wiki page, but I'm afraid I don't really understand it. Could you explain the concept in simpler terms?

Comment: @Maths The damping ratio simply tells you how close something is to being critically damped.  Critically damped is the least amount of damping that still keeps the spring from oscillating back and forth about the equilibrium.

Comment: Okay, so what variables would need to be tested, and what variables would be controlled in the scenario outlined?

Comment: @Maths I think I've done enough for now.  If you understand what controls and independent and dependent variables are, you should be able to take it from here.

Comment: I understand what independent and dependent variables are, but not how to figure out what they are in this scenario. It seems the frictional force is one variable, and I'm assuming that would need to be a controlled variable. Judging by the 'second order differential equation' the initial extension of the string is also a variable. I assume there must be many others, but I can't find any info on the topic. Doing a simple search for 'variables in dampening shm' finds nothing.

Comment: Are you able to explain the 'second order differential equation' for dampening at the wiki you linked to? I don't understand where the equation comes from, how it's used, and none of the letters/symbols in the equation are defined on the site..

Comment: @Maths differential equations are a topic in the mathematical field of analysis.  You can learn about them in college after taking a good calculus course.  As for independent and dependent variables, the dependent variables are what you measure as a response to changing the independent variables.  The time it takes the spring to stop might be a dependent variable, while the weight on the spring might be an independent variable.  Unless you are going to directly measure the frictional forces, they are neither.

Comment: Okay, so the variables so far are: initial extension of spring (independent), period of oscillation and time for spring to stop (dependent variable) and mass of weight on spring (independent variable). What other variables are there, or perhaps more importantly, how can I find what the other variables are?

Comment: @MathsStudent: Mark has given you a _lot_ of help here. It seems to me that the underlying problem is that you don't understand how to design an experiment. We can't really explain that to you here in the level of detail it sounds like you need. I'd suggest that you seek help directly from your teacher.