# How to determine viscous damping coefficient of spring?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, harmonic-oscillator, spring

I'm trying to determine the viscous damping coefficient of a spring $c$. Read about it on Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping).

The two equations which I have are:
$f=-cv$ and $ma+cv = -kx$

I know the spring constant $k=5$, the mass is $50\text{ }\mathrm{g}$ and the initial amplitude of the spring is $10\text{ }\mathrm{cm}$.

Comment: Dear @MathsStudent: Fortunately, I answered your question already: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8495/investigating-the-dampening-of-a-spring/8499#8499 Greets

Comment: Thanks Robert, but you didn't really. I can't use your equation (angular frequency = etc) as I don't know the angular frequency. It seems that the dampening coefficient is impossible to figure out, as not enough variables are ever known!

Comment: This is the third nearly identical questiion from You on "springs"!The problem is that You did not understand the answers to both of Your earlier questions. One thing I'd recommend, is: change Your "nome de guerre".  Vote to close

Comment: @MathsStudent: I think we have a problem of misunderstanding here. I think I pretty much answered your question. Please be specific in what you don't understand and what you mean by determining (measuring, calculating). In addition it might be useful to know at which point of your study you are and what intention you have with these spring questions. Greets

Comment: Sorry, but the questions really aren't the same. I've asked a number of similar questions on the one general topic, that does not make the questions identical. @Robert: What I don't understand is how to find 'c'. Using the information I supplied in this question, what is the value of 'c'? Can you calculate it? Nobody has been able to actually calculate the value of it yet.

Comment: @MathsStudent: Ok, you really mean calculation not measurement. Given $m$ and $k$ and the initial amplitude, your question cannot be answered. Remember, this is a constant you put in your model, you cannot derive it from it. Greets

Comment: ""Sorry, but the questions really aren't the same."" That questions are the same! You lack the basics to understand the math of an harmonic oscillator, thats all. So, what about Your nome de guerre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with the given $m$ and $k$ you indeed **cannot** calculate the damping coefficient $c$.

Remember that you just have a **model** where you put some constants in and you can only derive other constants which somehow depend on them.

The question concerning an actual **measurement** was answered in [Investigating the dampening of a spring](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8495/investigating-the-dampening-of-a-spring/8499#8499).

Greets

Comment: Okay, so what do I need to calculate c? As is obvious, I don't understand the maths behind the problem. If possible, can you just make up the data required and do an example calculation to find 'c' for me?

Comment: @MathsStudent: As I said, in a mathematical model you just define $c$. Calculation is only possible if you have a relation between different variables of a model such that the one you are looking for is already determined by the others. Greets

Answer (score -3):

fs=-kx this is Hooke's law if you look up Hooke's law you should find what the spring coefficient is as it is part of the Hooke theory