# How does damping coefficient vary with mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, spring, oscillators

Im going to be experimenting and I want top know what result I should get.

[image: Position time graph of mass on spring B is damping coefficient in picture]

This is basically what my graph is going to look like and it should help you get an idea of the experiment.

$$x(t)= x_0 e^{-\frac{c}{2m}}\cos (\omega t + \phi_0)$$

where c is damping coefficient

Comment: We'd get a better idea for the experiment if you showed the damping coefficient somewhere or you made it more obvious what you mean.  As is your question is extremely vague.

Comment: @JMac this is basically all the background you need http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8495/investigating-damped-harmonic-motion-in-a-spring/8499#8499 edit: ive forgotten how to use math jax sorry i added an equation

Comment: It depends on what they're modelling I guess.  If it's an ideal damper then no, it should have a set coefficient.  If it's a real system where we are just modelling some real behaviour as a dampening coefficient, the mass may affect it depending on how it interacts with the system.

Comment: It is usually under damping. So would damping coefficient decrease as mass increases @JMac

Comment: First, define which of your symbols is the "damping coefficient." I know what *I* think a damping coefficient is, but I don't have any reason to know if you think the same! (And there are plenty of real-world situations involving damping where your graph is *not* the response you would expect).

Comment: @alephzero I absolutely agree with that (which is why I prodded for more information).  I figure they were confusing damping ratio with damping coefficient, so that's what I put as my answer.  TBH they might have been asking something far more complex though.  That would be a lot more interesting for sure.

Answer (score 2):

No, the damping coefficient will not vary with mass.

Based on the back in forth in the comments, you are confusing a few concepts here.

The damping coefficient (subscript $c$) is a measure of applied force compared to velocity.  In terms of the equations of simple harmonic motion, this is a constant which has no terms dictated by mass.

Your mention of "under-damping" in the comments leads me to believe you are confusing damping coefficient $c$ with damping ratio $\zeta$.

$\zeta$ will determine the characteristics of the damped harmonic motion (i.e. under-damped, over-damped, critically damped).  $\zeta$ is given by the equation $$\zeta = \frac{c}{2 \sqrt {mk}}$$ where $c$, $m$ and $k$ are all constants.

You can see that mass will absolutely affect the damping ratio, but not the damping coefficient (since that is assumed constant).

In a real life scenario the damper may not perform the same if different masses are used; but traditionally with the idealized equations it just has a constant value.

I find the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Damped_harmonic_oscillator) has some good information on harmonic oscillation.  Also, if I misunderstood what your question was really about please let me know.

Comment: I was originally talking about damping coefficient but as it is not dependent on mass and wont change i can look at how mass affects the damping ratio. MANY THANKS! im sorry about being vague my understanding is not great of this topic!